# Como eu pego o objeto ou o valor de um tr com DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

```
function excluirDadosTabela (){
    $('#gridtabelaDocumentos').on('click', '.excluir', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var teste = $('#gridtabelaDocumentos').DataTable().row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        console.log(teste);
    });
}
```

do `DataTable() ...` pra frente não funciona !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta

```
var teste = $('#gridtabelaDocumentos').DataTable().row('seuid').data();
```

Comment: Vlw Maycon, resolveu meu problema, Obrigado !